# After tokenizing, has a letter token already carried typeface info and font size info?

Tags: tex-core

TeX is not very well understood for me, and there are so many details that I have to make some notes so that I can quickly understand what I have learned now when I go over it in the future. The working process is especially important for me.

In terms of tokenizing, for example

```
\font\ninerm=cmr9 \ninerm a
```

after tokenized finished, I got the token `a` with category code 11. Is this character token carried typeface info (computer modern roman) and size info (font size 9) with it? If not, when did TeX find this info for token `a` at the time of convering it to a box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a character token is essentially a pair of integers, character code and category code.

If a character token is encounted when TeX is typesetting a horizonal list then a characer node (which does hold the current font) is inserted into the list.

You can hold horizontal list in a box register so

```
\font\ninerm=cmr9 \ninerm \setbox0\hbox{a}  \showbox0
```

Shows that box 0 there does hold a character node that encodes cmr9.

Comment: then, when TeX get the size info for character token. for example, the height, depth, width for the character box? if character token is represented by the vector (character code, category code), how it distinguish the font size 10 `a` and size 9 `a`?

Comment: @Lucas when typesetting, I added more text

Comment: I still have one more question about this, since that box indeed holds a character node, its related info (like this character is cmr9) must be passed to the 'digestive tract'. I think this info is generated in the process of tokenzing (by executing the code `\font\nicerm=cmr9`), right?

Comment: @Lucas tex has a current font at all times (you can check with `\showthe\font` the current value  and that font is used for typesetting character nodes.

Comment: thanks, now I can add this knowledge to my notes.